# how can i automatically create telegram bot without using BotFAther and get token?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

i have to generate disposable telegram bots with random names and logins and then delete them. preferable using python

telegram bot documentation says that i have to use BotFather but that way i cant create bots automatically

Answer (score 2):

You can create new bots through BotFather, to automate that you could use a library that imitates the user such as [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)

By using that library with a telegram account you could send automaticaly generated commands to BotFather to create or delete a bot, and read the messages to recieve the tokens.